# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'

Tags: python, flask, alexa-skills-kit, ngrok, flask-ask

running ubuntu 18.10
python version 3.6.7
flask
flask-ask

trying to test my alexa skill via Ngrok before deployment but I keep running into an error when I go to launch my flask python file. I launches fine: 
$ python main.py

- Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 161-386-650

once in the alexa devolper console when I try to activate the skill I get this error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2019 18:22:55] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 728, in _flask_view_func
    ask_payload = self._alexa_request(verify=self.ask_verify_requests)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 662, in _alexa_request
    cert = verifier.load_certificate(cert_url)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 21, in load_certificate
    if not _valid_certificate(cert):
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 63, in _valid_certificate
    value = str(extension)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 779, in __str__
    return self._subjectAltNameString()
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 740, in _subjectAltNameString
    method = _lib.X509V3_EXT_get(self._extension)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2019 18:22:57] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 728, in _flask_view_func
    ask_payload = self._alexa_request(verify=self.ask_verify_requests)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 662, in _alexa_request
    cert = verifier.load_certificate(cert_url)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 21, in load_certificate
    if not _valid_certificate(cert):
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 63, in _valid_certificate
    value = str(extension)
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 779, in __str__
    return self._subjectAltNameString()
  File "/home/b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 740, in _subjectAltNameString
    method = _lib.X509V3_EXT_get(self._extension)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'
```

Comment: Your stack error is a cryptography issue check the version you have and update it in your requirements txt also isn’t Alexa expecting service over https you may want to service your ngrok from the secure channel instead

Comment: The question has been answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375054/alexa-skill-development-using-flask-ask-and-ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375054/alexa-skill-development-using-flask-ask-and-ngrok)